# Pass PHP variable to javascript inside php variable?

Tags: javascript, php

my script generates the image using php/html.  once it generates, i want to display the image without reloading the page.

I call the javascript(to change the image) function within the PHP itself. but i want to know how to pass new image name in this java script?

**$newpath as src variable**

Here is the code:

```
$newpath="output/".$outputfilename;

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'document.getElementById("latestimage").src="<newpath>";',
     '</script>';
```

Comment: why do you need to use the server to build your client side code?

Comment: the image should change after php execution.

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate your variable when echo, like:

```
$newpath="output/".$outputfilename;

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("latestimage").src="' . $newpath . '";
    </script>';
```